# Why does "myFileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;" incorrectly set other attributes

Tags: c#, .net

I had a problem copying a file because another business processes was setting the read only flag on either file. I didn't want to touch the source but always have the dest as read/write.

Here's the code I got to pared down to a simple console app:

```
using System.IO;

namespace TrialConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileSrc = "Src.txt";
            string fileDest = "Dest.txt";

            FileInfo destFileInfo = new FileInfo(fileDest);

            if (destFileInfo.Exists && destFileInfo.IsReadOnly)
                destFileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;

            Directory.CreateDirectory(destFileInfo.DirectoryName);
            (new FileInfo(fileSrc)).CopyTo(fileDest, true);

            destFileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
        }
    }
}
```

To run this you also need to create a Src.txt in your working directory.

When I first run this nothing appears to happen. the Dest.txt doesn't appear. The second time it complains about the destination file being readonly.

It was only when I showed Hidden and System files in explorer that I could see the Dest.txt, but it had the attributes HSAO set (O means offline in NTFS).

Why are these additional attributes being set? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time round the destFileInfo is created before the file is copied, it doesn't exist and it's attributes are 'undefined'.

The code then copies the file so now it does exist with defined attributes, but the destFileInfo still has the old data.

When the IsReadOnly attribute is set all the attributes written back to the file in one go. Those that are undefined in the stale destFileInfo object end up getting set.

Second time round is just the expected errors trying to overwrite a hidden system file.

The solution is to call `destFileInfo.Refresh();` after copying the file.